# How to check whether the user is a member of 2 different sharepoint Groups via infopath

Tags: infopath

My requirement is I need to show the section for the current user who is a Member of Group1 , after the approvals of few levels, I need to do the same for another Sharepoint Group like Group2. I have done this for Group1 by using "GetUserCollectionFromGroup". At the same time I need to check it for some other group by using the same webservice or by some other asmx.
 I'm unable to achieve this for the second group.
 Kindly help me out .

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own asmx webservice and deploy to virtual directory under sp application. Pass the current user info to this webservice and do operations what you need.